# When exporting APK with Proguard then getting errror code 1

Tags: java, android, apk

When I have to export an APK with Proguard then I am getting an error. I can't understand what is the actual problem.
My Error Console is like this:

```
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.servlet.BshServlet: can't find superclass or interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.AWTConsole: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.TextArea
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.AWTConsole: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.KeyListener
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.AWTConsole$1: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.AWTDemoApplet: can't find superclass or interface java.applet.Applet
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.AWTRemoteApplet: can't find superclass or interface java.applet.Applet
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.BeanShellBSFEngine: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.bsf.util.BSFEngineImpl
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.BshCanvas: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JComponent
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.ClassBrowser: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JSplitPane
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.ClassBrowser: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.ClassBrowser$1: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener
[2014-09-20 10:30:44 - MyApp] Warning: bsh.util.ClassBrowser$2: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener
```

Please give me solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

Comment: before that just clean project

Comment: @DigveshPatel same error after add your line.

Comment: plz check double btw you have added any java library to your project?

Comment: @DigveshPatel yes i have used so many libraries..for ex.itext-asign.jar.
then how to add this jar file in progaurd file.

Comment: -keep class com.example.mylibrary.** { *; }  this is for example like you can write  -keep class [yourlibmainpackagename].** { *; }

Comment: works or not?????????

Comment: @DigveshPatel i don't get package name of .jar file.i m not gettting it.i am confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61593/discussion-between-digvesh-patel-and-dipali).

Comment: just write and try -keep class javax.** { ; }

Comment: @DigveshPatel not allow chat in office

Comment: ohk no worry just try my last comment code its works

Comment: no its not Working...

Comment: @DigveshPatel not working...

Answer (score 1):

There is no proguard config that can make this work.

Android Java is the same programming language as standard Java, but not the same runtime environment. I see references to `java.awt`, `javax.swing` and `javax.servlet` in your Proguard error message. These classes don't exist on Android (the full [package list is here](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)) and no amount of Proguard config is going to add them.

You'll have to strip down the Beanshell library to leave out all the optional bits that you can't use. Then include the stripped down version in your project and try again.

Comment: I am working on proguard issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629487/obfuscation-minifyenabled-true-not-working-in-both-debug-and-release tried many links, didn't worked out.Please help me with this. Thanks in advance